# Proving sequence converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification, alternative-proof

I am trying to prove:

> Suppose that $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ are two sequences such that $\{a_n\}$ and $\{a_n+b_n\}$ converge. Prove that $\{b_n\}$ converges.

*Here is my first attempt:*

**Proof:** Suppose that $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ are two sequences such that $\{a_n\}$ and $\{a_n+b_n\}$ converge. Since $\{a_n\}$ converges, then for each $\epsilon>0$ there exist $N_1$ such that for all

$$n\geq N_1\Rightarrow|a_n-A|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$

The same follows for $\{a_n+b_n\}$, so for all

$$n\ge N_2\Rightarrow|a_n+b_n-(A+B)|<\epsilon.$$

Let $N=\max\{N_1,N_2\}$. Then, we have

$$|a_n+b_n-(A+B)|=|(a_n-A)+(b_n-B)|\le|a_n-A|+|b_n-B|.$$

Since $|a_n-A|>0$, it follows that

$$|b_n-B|\lt|a_n - A|+|b_n - B|\lt\epsilon.$$

Therefore $|b_n-B|\lt\epsilon$ for $n\ge N$. Thus, $\{b_n\}$ converges.

Is it completely wrong? What can I do to improve it? Thank you.

Comment: On the last line you've said $|a_n - A| + |b_n-B| < \epsilon$, but you only know that $|a_n + b_n - (A+B)| < \epsilon$.

Comment: You were OK up until "Then, we have $|a_n + b_n - (A+B)|$..." Instead start with what you want, namely $|b_n - B|$, and rewrite it as $|b_n + a_n - a_n  - (B + A - A)|$ and apply the triangle inequality to that.

Comment: It is not right. Use $b_n-B=((a_n+b_n)-(A+B))+(A-a_n)$.

Comment: I knew something was wrong. That makes much more sense. Thank you!

Comment: After taking the triangle inequality, I am left with |$a_n$+$b_n$ - (A+B)|+|A - $a_n$|. What do I do with the |A - $a_n$| portion?

Answer (score 1):

I think the comments already made clear how to attack the problem via $\;\epsilon-\delta\;$ and etc., but arithmetic of limits makes this much simpler:

$$b_n=(a_n+b_n)-a_n$$

and thus $\;\{b_n\}\;$ converges as it is the difference of two converging limits, and its limit is the difference

$$\;\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n+b_n) - \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$$